# Facebook UI call in ASP.NET MVC does not return the picture it should

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

Does anyone know why the picture attribute is not working in following Facebook UI call?

```
function postToWallUsingFBUi()
    {   
        var data=
        {
        method: 'stream.publish', 
        message: "Posted using FB.ui and picture.",
        display: 'iframe',
        caption: "Caption",
        name: "Name",
        //ver 1 picture: 'http://www.somedomain.com/albums/s339/rockaja/fb-520.png',   
        //ver 2 picture: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { PageId = Model.PageTabId }, Request.Url.Scheme)',
        picture: 'https://localhost/MyVirtualDirectory/Controller/Action/283659015078395',
        link: "http://www.mydomain.com/",  // Go here if user click the picture
        description: "Description field",
        actions: [{ name: 'action_links text!', link: 'http://www.mydomain.com' }]           
        }
        FB.ui(data, onPostToWallCompleted);
    }
```

As you can see the picture attribute  uses a picture from localhost. If i paste this URL into the browsers's Address field, i get the picture as expected.

I also commented out other two versions: 
version 1 is working properly as expected, but
version 2 is not working (this is an ASP.NET MVC call, but that fact does not affect the result).

May be it is due to the fact that i request a localhost-ed picture?!

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked on FB API so take my suggestion with a pinch of salt.

Based on my understanding of how Facebook works, whatever pictures you share on user's wall go into FB's data store first and are always pulled from that store.

Here, The Facebook API may be downloading the picture from the URL you have provided and push it into it's own store before publishing it on user's walls. When you use a localhost url, then the call to download the picture would obviously fail.

There must be another version of the API where you should be able to send the picture content as byte array. If there is, then you can load the picture from disk yourself and send the byte array in the API

Comment: To be honest i either don't know much things about this mystery world of FB (this is my first project going into production for FB). As i said: i'm afraid it's due to the reason i'm using a localhosted resource, you must be right!